# Derived typenames

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have plenty of different functions, which does quite similar operations, where the type and the size is encoded through the function names like the following:

```
int * operation_0_0_i( int a ) {
   int * result = new int[4];
   /* ... */
   return result;
}
int * operation_0_1_i( int a ) {
   int * result = new int[8];
   /* ... */
   return result;
}

float * operation_0_0_f( float a ) {
   float * result = new float[4];
   /* ... */
   return result;
}

float * operation_0_1_f( float a )  {
   float * result = new float[4];
   /* ... */
   return result;
}
```

Instead of having this confusingly amount of different functions I thought about using templates. My first try where templated structs, to realize derived type:

```
template< typename T >
struct A {
  using type = T;
  using array = std::array< T, 4 >;
};

template< typename T >
struct B {
   using type = T;
   using array = std::array< T, 8 >;
};
```

So that I can do something like that:

```
template< class U, typename T >
T* operation0( T a ) {
  typename U<T>::array a; 
  /* ... */
  return a.data();   // I know, that this is unsafe. Its just for this example                                                                                    
}

template< class U, typename T >
T* operation1( T a ) {
  typename U<T>::array a;                                                                                     
  /* ... */
  return a.data();
}

int main() {
   int * res1 = operation1<A, int>( 3 );
   int * res2 = operation2<B, int>( 8 );
   /* ... */
   return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this does not compile. The g++ tells me that

```
In function ‘T* operation0(T)’: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘U’ typename U<T>::array a;
```

Obviously the typename specifier is wrong at this position. But if I delete that specifier, g++ complains that

```
‘U’ is not a template U<T>::array a;
```

Does anyone knows, what I am doing wrong? And is there maybe an even better approach, maybe by using `std::variant`? Thanks for your time ;)

Sincerely

Comment: Did you also look into "non type template parameters"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to tell that your U class is template and take 1 parameter:

```
template<template <class > class U, typename T >
T* operation0( T _a ) {
  typename U<T>::array a;
  /* ... */
  return a.data();                                                              
}
```